# Repartitioning partitioned data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a skewed data problem, such that my smallest partitions are below 64MB and my largest partitions can be greater than 1GB. I've been contemplating a strategy to map a few small partitions to the same partition key, thus creating a partition comprised of partitions. This is all in the hope of reducing variance in task size as well as number of files stored on disk.

At one point in my Spark application, I need to operate on the (non-grouped) original partitions and to do so, will need to repartition by the original key. This brings me to my question:

Suppose I have two data sets as seen below. Each row is a tuple of the form **(partition_key, (original_key, data))**. In **data0**, you can see that original_key = 0 is on its own node, whereas original_key = 4 and original_key = 5 are together on the node containing partition_key = 3. In **data1**, things are not as organized.

If **data0** is partitioned by partition_key, and then partitioned by original_key, will a shuffle occur? In other words, does it matter during the second partitionBy call that **data0** is more organized than **data1**?

```
data0 = [
    (0, (0, 'a')),
    (0, (0, 'b')),
    (0, (0, 'c')),
    (1, (1, 'd')),
    (1, (1, 'e')),
    (1, (2, 'f')),
    (1, (2, 'g')),
    (2, (3, 'h')),
    (2, (3, 'i')),
    (2, (3, 'j')),
    (3, (4, 'k')),
    (3, (4, 'l')),
    (3, (5, 'm')),
    (3, (5, 'n')),
    (3, (5, 'o')),
]

data1 = [
    (0, (0, 'a')),
    (1, (0, 'b')),
    (0, (0, 'c')),
    (1, (1, 'd')),
    (2, (1, 'e')),
    (1, (2, 'f')),
    (3, (2, 'g')),
    (2, (3, 'h')),
    (0, (3, 'i')),
    (3, (3, 'j')),
    (3, (4, 'k')),
    (3, (4, 'l')),
    (1, (5, 'm')),
    (2, (5, 'n')),
    (3, (5, 'o')),
]

rdd0 = sc.parallelize(data0, 3).cache()
partitioned0 = rdd0.partitionBy(4)
partitioned0.map(lambda row: (row[1][0], row[1])).partitionBy(6).collect()

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data1, 3).cache()
partitioned1 = rdd1.partitionBy(4)
partitioned1.map(lambda row: (row[1][0], row[1])).partitionBy(6).collect()
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get the idea. So you're actually trying to make partitions larger? I would probably make more sense to actually focus on a redistribution of large partitions instead. Regarding the question at hand - if new key, partitioner, and number of partitions are the same then data shouldn't be moved. So in sense "more organized" will reduce the amount of data to shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

When you call re-partition shuffle kicks in.
How much of data get's shuffled is based on the original RDD.

As a side note: when you do `sc.parallelize(data0,3)` the 3 is mere guideline. If the default partition is <=3 then your rdd0 will have 3 partitions. If your data0 is on more HDFS blocks providing the partition number has no effect.